# Narrow generic to specific interface when filtering array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

EDIT: Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBNhgPZWQbwChkTkB9BAGzgGcaA5OAWwgC5kByAQUoCMBXJhiy4OyAD6cAysCYAHShGE4oHQgF9ChUJFiIUPAUMwrkEAB6QQ6GmhO4CxUgmzgI4dnBABPJyTBwvDSePhpaOtDwSMgy8orKDhZWNnYieESkyDQQighgwK7ByF6%20mtpuetEASvyKADwAKgB8jpkgzGxZYFCgAOZ%20ZvZQAMLY8nD5vMCUWN7sCSNjchPAUzNg3gDaALoDkDRg7AAUEEPsDQCUyAC8LSVhhBtyKAuj45PTszechoILYpIOLEFEohmotFRaLYAGpwGboCYODKkOQ9ABuExQUFqEFs12QmwGmWRmVJyHaLHYACJfkwaooAIxUgA0RLJgzSb2WH3WcwJ3D4fzB21Z7NJ%200OyBOQyut1aYvZUAgYH4UBAyG6-AgbLJmjF6mKtnpEDqtIWTVF7JJCopnSpwMUxqZloVHJUXJWa1m7E2QNkIP%20Ip14txkulaVlLWtrpISpVao12O1MeQevZBtoyGNdQdoLSTWDA12Awx8Mx4ZU7DNQwkMX98RlBGQAHpm8gABLYADuyHQ2GQAEkNd5nhqABbAWw4ZCKMAa0PIfjWaAHLzoZBYDi2U5pYej3i0U7IVzkSF0RgsAD8wZcIAOyGxjtxtTAePHk4AdI-cR%20YNNdEc343C034fju7pLJ6nwbB%20oBUPw6C4hWuAfhQ1Dnh0FwXB%20TBwHIgE4sBTatoO6pMN4yAuIhzLvrYk7FMgAAGMDUGAACyeFHBcjE0QIc7AFASqKBi4Aav2YBjigqLYLwihMMGmS3veSo0C%203ygRKyFQBcl6-v%200BHIBITeJGD5XCRABi%20l4Ng-BzkuiF-iApwKaQwAwFKKkvlc0YxnGqrqr5Kaxs%20lCSl5YWubqUWpmYlDZPKwUPsqAUEtsLZthZrEcXIxR2WMKwIHClAUX%20YUrmY8gbMUglwN4tillqNAxWmuoXAMmiaEAA).

I have a set of subclasses (defined as interfaces `A`, `B` for sake of example) which all extend `Base`. I have defined a list of rules that can act on any of those subclasses based on `_className` which is defined on `Base`.

I'm filtering the list of rules based on `_className` so that only relevant rules will be processed for a given `editor` input - however, I'm unable to figure out how (or if it's reasonably possible) for `rule.test(editor)` to know that it now is a single subclass (A or B).

Right now, I'm getting the common `Type 'A' is missing the following properties from type 'B': content, tabs - ts(2345)` error.

```js
    validate(editor: A | B) { // How do I type this to let test understand it's editor type based on _className?
        const ruleResults = this.rules.filter(rule => rule.editorCompatibility.includes(editor._className)).flatMap(rule => {
            const result = rule.test(editor)?.filter(this.isRuleResultTypeGuard)
            if (result) {
                return {
                    result: result,
                    summary: rule.summarize(result)
                }
            } else {
                return [] // FlatMap automatically filters empty arrays values
            }
        })
    ...
    }
```

I've tried user-defined type guards but didn't make much progress as they seem to be able to only identify a single type, rather than from a set of types.

Any direction would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to came up with something but I'm to sure i understood the problem correctly, take a look: https://tsplay.dev/WvEGRm

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzOP3w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks, I've added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The [mre] should be included as plaintext in the question itself; an external link is a great supplement to a question post but it isn't sufficient alone.  And any error you mention in the question should be present in the example; right now it seems the errors are different.